# cant create laravel usercontroller

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller

usually when I want to create controller I use php artisan

> php artisan make:controller UserController

but in this case I have error in my terminal

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
> Class 'User' not found

and I wanna use it for users page - update and display users, as well as route

> Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');

should I use it like that or something else? and why do I get error?

Comment: Did you made by any chance the command `php artisan make:auth` before that?

Comment: It's really not been created? your command seems okay to me, did you try doing that to other laravel project?

Comment: its fine, I wrote it in answer, controllers should have s at and in my case UsersController and not UserController

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you've used `User` class somewhere in the code (some controller probably). Find out where did you used it and add this clause to the top of that class:

```
use App\User;
```

Or just use full namespace, for example:

```
\App\User::get();
```

Comment: when I created migration User.php [model] was created but not controller

Comment: totally wrong... should go UsersController plurar , my bad